# How to get a "0" before "1" to "9" in a clock

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload, clock

My clock script is as follows. For some reason `if(minutes<10){minutes="0"+minutes;}` and `if(seconds<10){seconds="0"+seconds;}` will add a `0` before a number less than `10`, but it won't do it for the hours. Any advice on how to fix it?

```
<script>
 function TimeUpdate() {
  var now = new Date(), hours = now.getHours(), minutes = now.getMinutes(), seconds = now.getSeconds();

  // The 1st "if" does not work.
  if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
  if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
  if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}

  // (This works) AM or PM option
  if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {var TimeOfDay = "PM";}
  else {var TimeOfDay = "AM";}

  // (This works) Converts the hours from 24 to 12
  if (hours > 12) {hours = hours - 12;}

  // This sets the hours to a specific number.
  // This is used only for this demonstration.
  hours = 5;

  // (This works) Puts everything together
  var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay;

  // (This works) The clock <div>
  var MyClock = document.getElementById('clock');

  // (This works) Writes the "CurrentTime" to the clock's <div>
  MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;
  var t = setInterval (function () {TimeUpdate ()}, 1000);
 }

 // (This works) This loads the clock onto the page.
 window.onload = TimeUpdate;
</script>

<p id="clock"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're overwriting your check. Move that block of code further down:

```js
function TimeUpdate() {
       var now = new Date(),
         hours = now.getHours(),
         minutes = now.getMinutes(),
         seconds = now.getSeconds();


       if (minutes < 10) {
         minutes = "0" + minutes;
       }
       if (seconds < 10) {
         seconds = "0" + seconds;
       }

       // (This works) AM or PM option
       if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {
         var TimeOfDay = "PM";
       } else {
         var TimeOfDay = "AM";
       }

       // (This works) Converts the hours from 24 to 12
       if (hours > 12) {
         hours = hours - 12;
       }

       // This sets the hours to a specific number.
       // This is used only for this demonstration.
       hours = 5;
       // The 1st "if" does not work.
       if (hours < 10) {
         hours = "0" + hours;
       }
       // (This works) Puts everything together
       var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay;

       // (This works) The clock <div>
       var MyClock = document.getElementById('clock');

       // (This works) Writes the "CurrentTime" to the clock's <div>
       MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;
       var t = setInterval(function() {
         TimeUpdate()
       }, 1000);
     }

      // (This works) This loads the clock onto the page.
     window.onload = TimeUpdate;
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place

```
if (hours < 10) {
         hours = "0" + hours;
       }
```

after

```
if (hours > 12) {
         hours = hours - 12;
       }
```

since it has to be true for hours of 13-21 (1-9 PM) as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Watch out for that code. That's a recursive function, you'll blow your computer memory in no time. Please remove the `TimeUpdate()` from inside itself**

```js
function TimeUpdate() {
  var now = new Date(),
    hours = now.getHours(),
    minutes = now.getMinutes(),
    seconds = now.getSeconds();


  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  // (This works) AM or PM option
  if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {
    var TimeOfDay = "PM";
  } else {
    var TimeOfDay = "AM";
  }

  // (This works) Converts the hours from 24 to 12
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }

  // This sets the hours to a specific number.
  // This is used only for this demonstration.
  hours = 5;
  // The 1st "if" does not work.
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  // (This works) Puts everything together
  var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay;

  // (This works) The clock <div>
  var MyClock = document.getElementById('clock');

  // (This works) Writes the "CurrentTime" to the clock's <div>
  MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;

}

// (This works) This loads the clock onto the page.
var t = setInterval(function() {
  TimeUpdate()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Comment: This works even better. Since it loads a second after the page loads it allows my data JS to be loaded and displayed correctly before this one.

Comment: Glad it helped. Close your questions if your problem is fixed. Regards